# Typescript, map one object into another?

Tags: typescript

I have two objects, and my custom map function to map props of one object into values of another, e.g:

```js
const obj1 = {
  host: 'clientNameHost',
  pass: 'clientNamePass',
};

const obj2 = {
  clientNamePass: '12345',
  clientNameHost: 'http://localhost:3000',
};

const mapParams = <T, K>(source: T, params: K) => Object.entries(params)
.reduce((acc, [param, sourceProp]) => ({ ...acc, [param]: source[sourceProp] }), {});

mapParams(obj2, obj1) //{host: "http://localhost:3000", pass: "12345"}
```

I'm having a hard time, trying to type this function. Is there some way to type properly mapParams function?

Comment: You can write `sourceProp as keyof T` like so: `const mapParams = <T, K>(source: T, params: K) => Object.entries(params).reduce((acc, [param, sourceProp]) => ({ ...acc, [param]: source[sourceProp as keyof T] }), {});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to narrow the generic types in order to show the relation between keys and values in both arguments:

```
const obj1 = {
    host: 'clientNameHost',
    pass: 'clientNamePass',
  } as const;

  const obj2 = {
    clientNamePass: '12345',
    clientNameHost: 'http://localhost:3000',
  } as const;

  const mapParams = <T extends Record<string, any>, K extends keyof T, P extends Record<T[K], any>>(source: T, params: P) => Object.entries(params)
  .reduce((acc, [param, value]) => ({ ...acc, [param]: source[value as T[K]] }), {});

  console.log(mapParams(obj1, obj2)) //{host: "http://localhost:3000", pass: "12345"}
```

Key parts:

- `T extends Record<string, any>` first type is a Record with string keys
- `K extends keyof T` respresents keys of the `T`
- `P extends Record<T[K], any>` crucial part - we want object which will have keys equal values in `T`
- `as const` was added in order to properly infer the narrowed types

Above types create a bound between first argument values and second argument keys.

PS. sorry for reverting arguments order.

Answer (score 0):

When typing functions what I care about the most is argument and return types.

You could type the arguments like this:

```
<InputProps, TargetProps extends Record<keyof TargetProps, keyof InputProps>>(
  source: InputProps,
  params: TargetProps
) => ...
```

Typescript will complain if the second object doesn't match the first one.

For the return value you can define a utility type as follows:

```
type MapFrom<A, B> = Record<keyof A, B[keyof B]>;
```

By using the `Object.proptotype.entries` type argument we avoid having to cast `sourceProp`.

To keep the function signature we need to assert the type of `initialValue` in the reduce.

I also use const assertions to give object literals readonly properties

This is the complete result:

```
type MapFrom<A, B> = Record<keyof A, B[keyof B]>;

const obj1 = {
  host: "clientNameHost",
  pass: "clientNamePass"
} as const;

const obj2 = {
  clientNamePass: "12345",
  clientNameHost: "http://localhost:3000"
} as const;

const mapParams = <InputProps, TargetProps extends Record<keyof TargetProps, keyof InputProps>>(
  source: InputProps,
  params: TargetProps
) =>
  Object.entries<keyof InputProps>(params).reduce(
    (acc, [param, sourceProp]) => ({
      ...acc,
      [param]: source[sourceProp]
    }),
    {} as MapFrom<TargetProps, InputProps>
  );

const obj3 = mapParams(obj2, obj1);
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-fire-482se) you can try it out.